# Stop Quartz.Net SampleJob

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am new to Quartz.net and I have been following [these](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx) tutorials to get it started. Since I have configured the logging system I noticed that the sampleJob that he recommends to check is still running:

17:13:15 [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob running...
17:13:20 [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob run finished.
17:13:25 [ServerScheduler_Worker-4] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob running...
17:13:30 [ServerScheduler_Worker-4] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob run finished.
17:13:35 [ServerScheduler_Worker-5] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob running...
17:13:40 [ServerScheduler_Worker-5] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob run finished.
17:13:45 [ServerScheduler_Worker-6] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob running...
17:13:50 [ServerScheduler_Worker-6] INFO  Quartz.Server.SampleJob - SampleJob run finished.

how do I stop this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`IScheduler` has different methods if you want to:

Pause a job: `PauseJob`
Pause all jobs: `PauseAll`
Pause a trigger: `PauseTrigger`
Unschedule a job: `UnscheduleJob`

More references [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/IScheduler.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Could be that /quartz_jobs.xml file has been occasionally left in service folder.